# Android: Insert Bitmap to Images.Media always get black background to stored image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

I am inserting the image using [InsertImage](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), but every time when image is stored on sd card its background become black. How can I remove that black background?

My code is:

```
> Bitmap Img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
>              R.drawable.ic_launcher); String path =
> Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), Img, "myImg", "Image");
```

Answer (score 4):

please use this format before saving images in SD card ----->>> Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG  if you use Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG your problem will repeat

```
public class SDCard {

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String filename)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/JANU");

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();

    }
    File imagefile = new File(folder, filename);
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imagefile);

    boolean bit = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fout);

}
```